# How to exclude certain logging level from [Test worker] logger

Tags: java, slf4j, wiremock

I use `WireMock` library for unit testing and every time I receive a lot of the DEBUG logs:

[image]

I try to exclude logs with `logbak-test.xml' file but it give an unexpectedly result: even I create an empty file - no one log outputted:

```xml
<configuration>
</confuguration>
```

But I need to receive ERROR and WARN logs, etc...

So, my WireMock configuration:

```java
    @ConfigureWireMock
    protected Options options = wireMockConfig()
            .port(8088)
            .notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true))
            .extensions(ResponseTemplateTransformer.builder()
                    .global(false)
                    .maxCacheEntries(10L)
                    .build());
```

logbak-test.xml:

```xml
<configuration debug="false" scan="true">
    <!-- Turning down the wiremock logging -->
    <logger name="com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="wiremock.org" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="WireMock" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- wiremock has per endpoint servlet logging -->
    <logger name="/" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

application.properties:

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=TRACE
```

- How to receive exactly ERROR, INFO and WARN logs?

There are the code where I need to get a log:

```java
@Slf4j
public class TryCatchResponseUtil {
    public void logiingTest(){
        log.error("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `verbose` parameter of `Slf4jNotifier` to false to disable logging.